# My custom wave file can't be prepared by mediaplayer. Prepare failed.: status =0x1

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, wav

I have a problem with a media player. It won't prepare after setting data source. I have custom wav file with metadata at the end of it. Other wav files are played noramly by media player like my custom files in other players.

Here is were I want to play a file.

```java
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

        String filePath = path+"/"+list_pos[position];

        final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(filePath);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is my cutom wav file. I have to add some metadata to my file and I figured that I can add it at the end. It play normaly in other players.

```java
public void save(String name,String surname, String title,String description){
        state = false;

        String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        String dateAndTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd',' HH:mm:ss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        String metadata = name+"#" +surname+"#"+title+"#"+dateAndTime+"#"+description;

        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(status)){

            File recording  = new File(fileName);

            try {
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(recording);
                os.write(prepareWavHeader(file.size() * Constans.bufferSize));
                for (byte[] b:file) {
                    os.write(b);
                }
                os.write(metadata.getBytes());
                os.close();
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    public byte[] prepareWavHeader(int pcmDataLengthInBytes)
    {
        int totalDataLen = pcmDataLengthInBytes + 36;
        byte[] wavHeader = prepareWavFileHeader(16,pcmDataLengthInBytes,totalDataLen,
                Constans.sampleRate,Constans.numberOfChannels,
                Constans.sampleRate*Constans.numberOfChannels*16/8);
        return wavHeader;
    }

    private byte[] prepareWavFileHeader(int bitsPerSample,long totalAudioLen,long totalDataLen,
                                        long longSampleRate, int channels, long byteRate){
        byte[] header = new byte[44];

        header[0] = (byte)'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header
        header[1] = (byte)'I';
        header[2] = (byte)'F';
        header[3] = (byte)'F';
        header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
        header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[8] = (byte)'W';
        header[9] = (byte)'A';
        header[10] = (byte)'V';
        header[11] = (byte)'E';
        header[12] = (byte)'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk
        header[13] = (byte)'m';
        header[14] = (byte)'t';
        header[15] = (byte)' ';
        header[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
        header[17] = 0;
        header[18] = 0;
        header[19] = 0;
        header[20] = 1; // format = 1
        header[21] = 0;
        header[22] = (byte) channels;
        header[23] = 0;
        header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
        header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
        header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8); // block align
        header[33] = 0;
        header[34] = (byte) bitsPerSample; // bits per sample
        header[35] = 0;
        header[36] = (byte)'d';
        header[37] = (byte)'a';
        header[38] = (byte)'t';
        header[39] = (byte)'a';
        header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
        header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

        return header;
    }
```

Comment: looking at the wav file format it seems like part of the header specifies how long it is. the player may check that and throw error. if you update that it will try to play it though.